# How to skip the "\n" in the output while using the readlines() method?

Tags: python, linux, file, readlines

I want to read a notepad file by using the readlines() method.

```
f = open('/home/user/Desktop/my_file', 'r')
print(f.readlines())
```

The output is:
`['Hello!\n', 'Welcome to Barbara restaurant. \n', 'Here is the menu. \n']`

As you see the newlines will be mentioned in the output, too. What should I do? Note that I want to use the readlines() method.

P.S! My operating system is Linux Ubuntu and here's the link to my file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1baVVxZjXmFwo_3uwdUCsrwHOG-Dlfo38/view?usp=sharing

I want to get the output below:

```
Hello!
Welcome to Barbara restaurant.
Here is the menu.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****Update**** (Since you need the **readlines()** method)

```
f = open('/home/user/Desktop/my_file', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    print(line, end='')
```

**Output**

```
Hello!
Welcome to Barbara restaurant.
Here is the menu.
```

---

****Original****

You can read then split each line

```
f = open('/home/user/Desktop/my_file', 'r')
print(f.read().splitlines())
```

**Output**

> ['Hello!', 'Welcome to Barbara restaurant. ', 'Here is the menu. ']

Answer (score 0):

A pipelined approach going trough every line once on demand. This can be more memory friendly with the downside of being a bite more complicated.

```
f = open('/home/user/Desktop/my_file', 'r')

lines_iter = map(str.strip, f)  # note you can only go through this once!
lines = list(lines_iter)        # optional: move everything to a list

f.close() # don't forget to close - but only AFTER using the map object
```

##### Output -

```
>>> print(lines)
['Hello!', 'Welcome to Barbara restaurant.', 'Here is the menu.']
>>> print("\n".join(lines))
Hello!
Welcome to Barbara restaurant.
Here is the menu.
```

---

Depending on the usage you don't need to move it into a list.
But the file object needs to be accessible until the map object worked over it.

Comment: I get a syntax error while running the second line of your code.